# What functionalities are blocked if you don't have a PS+/XBLG subscription?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Wondering if I should buy MHW on PS4 or wait for PC (Where online won't need a subscription, probably)

So are there any major functionalities of MHW that are blocked if you don't have a console Online Subscription? What functionalities in particular are available/not available?

And maybe dipping into something a little bit more of opinion, is the game fine if played offline, or is playing offline missing a lot of the experience?

Comment: I think the game is fine if played solo/offline.  Playing with friends is a lot of fun, but I would rather play solo than with randoms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without PS Plus or Xbox Live, you cannot play online multiplayer in Monster Hunter World. This is typical of games with online components. You will only be able to play single-player without a subscription.

[Here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunterWorld/comments/7qlfua/do_i_require_a_ps_subscription_to_play_mhw_online/) some [other](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/71fzy4/will_mhw_require_ps_plus_for_online_multiplayer_s/) threads affirming this and [here](http://gearnuke.com/monster-hunter-world-new-details-revealed-will-require-ps-plusxbox-live-multiplayer/) is an article about it.

> Monster Hunter World will also require PS Plus or Xbox Live Gold for multiplayer, as confirmed on the livestream.

Event Quests will not be locked behind a subscription (even though technically that would require online functionality to receive). See posts in [this thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/211368-monster-hunter-world/76247659).